# Links browser and Vim together

Tags: vim, browser

I've been reading [bloomberg.com/whatiscode](http://bloomberg.com/whatiscode) and its a long webpage. 
I also recently started using Vim.
At the moment, to take notes, I copy paste some parts of the webpage onto a text file.

I would **like to do** the following:

- browse a webpage in links, select text and copy it on to vim in the same terminal
- or have vim show me a webpage, select text and copy it on to a file

I am **not able to** do these things because:

- I don't know how to select text in links (the man page didn't have any info)
- I don't know how to make vim show a webpage

I googled for "vim links browser" and saw this is as the most relevant result http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4315 but it allows one to use lynx in vim and not links.

Any suggestion on how I can go about this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, VIM has no built-in browsing capabilities and if it has, they are most likely quite limited. If you want to browse from the command line, there is a couple of tools you might want to have a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line.
Regarding selecting text in Vim, use its 'VISUAL MODE'.

Comment: thank you. I know how to select text in vim but not in links browser.

Comment: You could always run the `links` command from within `vim` by pressing escape, then use the `!` at the `:` prompt, e.g. `:!links bloomberg.com/whatiscode` ..

Comment: The script appears to be Windows-specific, by the way.  If you are able to run `links`, that probably is *not* in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use tmux ([vim-mode keybindings](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-tmux/))
Imagine you have split screen where one pane is the browser where you want to copy text from while the other(s) are destination(s).

"**ctrl+b [**" enters visual mode

"**h/j/k/l**" navigates the screen

"**v**" sets the selection marker

"**y**" copies the selection to tmux buffer

"**ctrl+b o**" selects other panes in the window (or ctrl+b arrow if you dont mind reaching that far)

"**ctrl+b ]**" pastes the tmux buffer

It all sounds like a lot of work but once you develop the muscle memory for this mode of working it is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it would be great to be able to navigate text within Links (like Vim) and copy it to the clipboard. I haven't found a way to do that with macOS's default zsh yet.

Here's my 1-liner solution for how I get web info (e.g. definitions) into vim quickly:

```
links "www.google.com/search?q=define+svd" -dump | vim -
```

According to Links' help info, '-dump' outputs the formatted webpage to stdout. I then pipe it into Vim using the '-' flag, which allows Vim to read from stdout. You're then in Vim with the Links-formatted page (text and not HTML) ready to select text and copy etc.

You could of course create a binding/alias for this in your shell and/or Vim.

Bit of a hacky solution, but it's good if you know in advance that you want to ship the text output of a webpage to Vim for editing.